# Bash execution process

Tags: bash, shell, unix, operating-system

I wrote a bash script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
var=2
echo result: $(expr "$var" + 1) > test.out
```

I run it from the shell with `./test` command and it creates the file test.out and the output into the file

```
result: 3
```

I'm curious to understand more in details the underling steps the bash uses to substitute the values, redirect the stdout and produce an output into the file.

Could you please explain how the OS is handling the execution of this script?

Comment: 'expr' is a program used in ancient shell code to do math. In Posix shells like bash, use $(( expression )). In bash, ksh88+, mksh/pdksh, or zsh, you can also use '(( expression ))' or 'let expression'.

Comment: After seeing that the first two bytes of the file are `#!`, the OS executes `/bin/bash` with the argument `./test`

Comment: After executing the script, the OS doesn't do very much.  `bash` will ask the OS to execute `expr` with arguments `2`, `+`, and `1` (and `expr`, but ignore that detail) and it will ask the os to open the file `test.out`, but beyond that the OS is not involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a simple schema with the main steps that happens after the execution of the script:

```
* --> Script execution -> Shell --> Expansion --> Command execution
```

Before the execution of the command inside the script, first the shell prepares the commands as filters with redirection and input/output pipes. After that, there is the shell expansions when the shell looks for special characters and substitues them if any.

About the substitution, it follows this order:

1. substitution of the commands: the command among backquotes are executes and substituted by their result
2. substitution of variables and parameters: the values of the variables (ex. $var) are expanded
3. substitution of metacharacters (* ?) into filenames with pattern matching